# Scroll first UICollectionViewCell to centre of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which stretches across my `UIViewController`.  I'm populating this with a horizontal line of `UICollectionViewCells`.  Here's my view:

[image]

When a user taps on a contact, I scroll it to the centre of the view and display information below.

My problem is with the first and last cells - if I attempt to scroll these to the centre, they won't, because there is nothing on the left of the first cell, or right of the last cell.  Is there something I can set (like an offset, or inset, or edge or something) which will allow this first and last cell to scroll straight to the middle of the `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Interface Builder, you can set the inset parameters for a `UICollectionView` here:

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: bsarr007 for president!

Answer (score 0):

```
yourCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftWidth, 0, rightWidth);
```